# React Material-UI Webpack Hot Reload Injecting Duplicate Styles in <head> on Save

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I can see that with webpack-dev-server HMR enabled react-hot-loader, material-ui is injecting new styles (`<style>`) into  on every change so when I switch from lightTheme to darkTheme its injecting a number of styles adding to the previous styles. so when I change back to lightTheme and save; its once again adding the light theme styles after the previous darkTheme styles and initial lightTheme styles. This is causing some css conflicts and as a result does not change back to lightTheme unless I refresh page

Is this expected functionality and it just doesn't play nice with react-hot-loader or is there a solution to this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'
import { Router, Link } from '@reach/router'
import MainLayout from './layouts/main/mainLayout'
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core'
import { lightTheme } from './themes/theme'

const App = (): JSX.Element => {

return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Router>
            <MainLayout path="/" />
        </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
 )
}

export default hot(App)
```

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this? I have the same issue and it is quite annoying.

Comment: From what I've across in various MaterialUI threads on this matter is that MaterialUI doesnt cater well to HMR, at the least the HMR mechanism popular with Webpack. In addition to the idea that page/state reloads give a more realistic, although inconvenient, functionality of your application; I ended up removing HMR as it wasnt worth the trouble. Material UI for me has been more trouble than its worth at least with the full fledged MaterialUI involvment.

Comment: So I have a partial fix, at least one that worked for me. I disabled strict mode for react and magically the issue went away. I do not think this is a good solution by any means but it does lend some evidence about the root cause. Anyway, just thought I'd share.